# Difference in behavior of Scanner nextLine() between Android Studio Intellij and Netbeans

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, netbeans

I am reading the same pipe-delimited file using Netbeans (for testing basic technique) and Android Studio (for actual application) and getting different results. Work OK on Netbeans. File contains 767 lines and I read all 767. Same code on Android Studio randomly breaks some of the lines in the middle, thus creating more than 1000 lines. Here is the offending code:

```
String URL = "http://nycjazzrecord.com/Calendar/CalendarUTF8(Dec2016).txt";
int i;
       java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(URL);
       Scanner input = new Scanner(url.openStream());

       for (i = 0; input.hasNext() && i<eventCalendar.length; i++) {
           String temp = input.nextLine();
           eventCalendar[i] = temp.split("\\|",9);
       }
```

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: It is also his post.

Comment: Can specify a spot where there's an extra line break?

Comment: I was not sure the original question was posted, hence duplicate. One example is line 272, "Duduka Da Fonsceca...." There are 4 lines, almost identical, and this lines breaks between "...9:30" and "pm...".